# Year to Century Function Code Understanding

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a year, return the century it is in. The first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200.  For year = 1905, the output should be centuryFromYear(year) = 20. For year = 1700, the output should be centuryFromYear(year) = 17.

Solution:

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return year/100
    else:
        return int(year/100) + 1
```

I tried the following code:

```
def centuryFromYea(year):
    return year % 100
```

I tried other solutions and received errors. I need an explanation on why the if statement is set to equals to 0 and if true return to year/100. I also need an explanation on the else return.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Perhaps you could provide an explanation of the parts of it that you *do* understand? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278797/3001761

Comment: I don't understand why the if statement is true . Does if x % number == 0: always True?

Comment: If it was always true, what would the point of testing it be?! It's only true when `x % number` is equal to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`year % 100` value is the same like `year / 100`  ONLY if `year % 100 == 0`.

Example: If year is 2000 both expressions will return 20.

If it is not the case it means that the year is not a round multiple of 100.

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.) The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand [2].

Comment: So in this case the statement is False and in return the input would be for example int(1705/100)+1 = 18 because it is defined as an Int?

Comment: Correct. This the logic here.

Comment: Perfect! the problem makes sense now :D.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(year):
    if year % 100 != 0:
        return year//100 +1
    else:
        return year/100
```

Comment: The question was asking for an _explanation_: "*I need an explanation on why the if statement is set to equals to 0 and if true return to year/100. I also need an explanation on the else return.*".

Comment: the if statements tells if the remainder for year/100 is equal to 0 then divide year to 100 (since the remainder is 0, the result would be an integer). And the else statements tells to divide year to 100 and add 1 to the result of this division and return an integer not float.  NOTE: I don't think, the code you pasted out there is the answer for the given question.

Answer (score -1):

```
if statement is for the cases like 1200,1300,1700,
```

where year%100 will result 0.

else statement is for all the other cases like 
   1201(13),1705(17) ,  where year%100 is not equal to 0.

```
Ex. 1201, solution: 
centuryFromYear(year) = 13
1201 % 100 = 1 which is not equal to zero
so it should return (1201/100) + 1  = 13

not : 1201/100 = 12
```